# Sorry! Something went wrong during authentication between Kibana and Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS ElasticSearch with Cognito and getting the following error when trying to login

`Sorry! 
Something went wrong during authentication between Kibana and Amazon Cognito.
What happened?
User: x:x:x::xx:x is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet`

My AWS ES cluster access policy looks like

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/CognitoAccessForAmazonES"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttp*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx:domain/elastic-blah/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "xx.xx.xx.xx/32"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible issue as described in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html#es-cognito-auth-troubleshooting) link. Ensure the authenticated role has appropriate permissions to access your ES domain.

The Amazon Cognito authenticated role needs es:ESHttp* permissions for the domain (/*) to access and use Kibana. Check that you added an access policy as specified in Allowing the Authenticated Role.

Comment: Resolved. Issue was with not enough permissions for Cognito Auth Role

Comment: Mark it as answer if it helped!

Comment: That's what logic would seem to indicate, as that's how S3 and KMS work also. Regardless it didn't work for me. I will continue to check

Comment: Disturbed by how the Console is doing half of the job when enabling Cognito access to kibana. But at least it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and giving more permissions to the Auth Role from Cognito solved the issue.