# The ambiguous role mapping rules for: cognito with microsoft active directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-cognito, amazon-elasticsearch

I've encountered following error message when I'm trying to integrate AWS Cognito and AWS ElasticSearch with AD. I've setup AD and cognito integration but after login with AD-User in AD Console, I've encountered following message. But when I've created user in AWS Cognito and login with its authentication, it was working. Please let me what I've missed to configure it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Check whether the user pool id and app client id from user pool configurations are correctly configured in federated identities page. Also, check whether correct template is selected for authentication to Active Directory purposes, i.e., ‘Allow access for one or more AWS accounts or IAM users’ is selected.

•   Please ensure that the Amazon Elasticsearch domain has sufficient access to the authorized AD users and groups through the access control policy. Also, check the IAM roles with the exact same name as AD groups are authorized or permitted for authentication with Active Directory or not.

•   If using ADFS for federated identities with Microsoft Active Directory, check the replying party SAML 2.0 SSO service URL in ADFS configuration. Also, check the claim rules in ADFS and the issuance policy in ADFS. On the AWS side in elastic search console, check the roles key configuration under optional SAML settings.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/configure-saml-single-sign-on-for-kibana-with-ad-fs-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

[Sorry! Something went wrong during authentication between Kibana and Amazon Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085475/sorry-something-went-wrong-during-authentication-between-kibana-and-amazon-cogn)